# How to display one of my column's values in gridview footer on a label

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I want to display the values from column named "total" on a label in my 
GridView footer.

The value of "total" column is same along every row so it does not matter which ever cell is chosen as long as we are in that column.

I am using a template-field for my column "total" and I am hiding it by making its visibility=false. so what i want is i want to display the value from my column named total on to a label which is inside my gridview

Here is the code sample I have tried, but its giving an error:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
int total;
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
        { 
            total = Convert.ToInt32(((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["total"].ToString()); 
        } 
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer) 
        { 
            Label lblamount7 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label27"); 
            lblamount7.Text =total.ToString(); // use of unassigned local variable 'total'
        }
    }
```

this is the aspx of the hidden column
 '> '>

Comment: You can store the required value in hiddenfield, then use it saperately

Comment: why putting a value on it while you're hiding it? What's the main purpose to get the total?

Comment: the purpose of getting total is merely because i am making a budget page so i just need to retrive total which is stored in another table and display it on gridview footer so that i can present it in such a form :
total allocate=total
total expenditure=expen
balance left=balance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For hiding the column take a Hiddeneeild in the Template-Field of GridView. The syntax will be like

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
 <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Total") %>'/>


                        </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Now to calculate total and show it in footer of GridView you can do like

```
int total = 0;
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if(e.Row.RowType==DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
total += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Total"));
}
if(e.Row.RowType==DataControlRowType.Footer)
{
Label lblamount7 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTotal");
lblamount7.Text = total.ToString();
}
}
```

It will surely work. Good Luck and do comment if it worked.

Comment: i dont want to calculate total, total is the name of my column whose value i want to retrieve on a label in my gridview footer thats it. i m hiding the using template field now i just want to retrieve its value and display it on label27 thats it

Comment: For hiding the value use hidden feild as u can retreive easily on RowDdataBound. And you will retrieve that value on label with the same above code. Make yourself a bit clear because in question u want to find total

Comment: //declaring global variable
static int total=0;
 
// under gridview RowDataBound Event
 
Collapse | Copy Code

if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
 
            total = Convert.ToInt32(((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["total"].ToString());
 
        }
 
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            Label Label27 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label25");
            Label27.Text =total.ToString();
        }

 
this is what worked for me Smile | :)

Comment: If necessary edit the answer and if it worked mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

It think you need parentheses around your DataRowView cast -- DataItem["total"] does not exist:

Change this:

```
total = Convert.ToInt32((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem["total"].ToString());
```

to

```
total = Convert.ToInt32(((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["total"].ToString());
```

--EDITS

You need to define total outside of the RowDataBound procedure and initialize it to 0.  Also, please note the use of "+=" -- I assume you want a running total from each of your columns.  If not, change that back to just "=" which will grab the last total in your data rows.

```
private int total = 0;
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
    { 
        total += Convert.ToInt32(((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["total"].ToString()); 
    } 
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer) 
    { 
        Label lblamount7 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label27"); 
        lblamount7.Text =total.ToString(); 
    }
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: now its giving this error: lblamount7.Text =total.ToString();// use of unassigned local variable 'total'

Comment: assign total as
 int total=0;

Comment: if i make int total =0 its not showing anything on the label its showing label as it is 'label'

Comment: Where are you defining total? It needs to be defined outside of the GridView1_RowDataBound procedure.